# Inherit from @objc protocol

Tags: swift, inheritance

I have this protocol inheritance

```
@objc protocol Base {}

protocol Some : Base {}
```

And the code to check it `main.swift`:

```
import Foundation

class Model1 : NSObject {}

extension Model1 : Some {}


class Model2 : NSObject, Some {}


func test() {
    let m1: NSObject = Model1()
    let m2: NSObject = Model2()

    print("m1 is Some? \(m1 is Some)")
    print("m2 is Some? \(m2 is Some)")

    print("m1 is Base? \(m1 is Base)")
    print("m2 is Base? \(m2 is Base)")
}

test()
```

Interestingly, the output differs for `swiftc` and `swift`

```
swiftc main.swift && ./main
m1 is Some? true
m2 is Some? true
m1 is Base? false
m2 is Base? false
```

vs

```
swift main.swift
m1 is Some? true
m2 is Some? true
m1 is Base? true
m2 is Base? false
```

**But the question is – why I cannot cast any of them to `Base`?**

If I add `@objc` to `Some`, then every test would pass with `true`. But I cannot do this at the moment, that's a topic for another SO ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42024990/652122)).

```
swiftc --version
Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Comment: Your question is a bit odd: First you prove inconsistent behavior between `swift` and `swiftc` and then you go on to a somewhat unrelated question. Have you tried casting them to `Base`? What happened?

Comment: @idmean each `print` has `is` operator. "The is operator checks at runtime whether the expression can be cast to the specified type."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [swift-users](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20170206/004648.html), seems like a known issue, to be fixed: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1175

Also now reported as https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3882