# Swift compiler crashes on associatedtype in @objc protocol

Tags: swift

This code sample breaks Swift compiler:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol Some {
    associatedtype W
}

extension Some {
    func takeW(w: W) -> Void {
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0  swift                    0x0000000104f583ad PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x0000000104f57b56 SignalHandler(int) + 790
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffe7eadbba _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib   0x00007fffe7e21258 malloc + 24
4  swift                    0x0000000101f8cd32 llvm::Value* llvm::function_ref<llvm::Value* (unsigned int)>::callback_fn<swift::irgen::emitArchetypeWitnessTableRef(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::ArchetypeType>, swift::ProtocolDecl*)::$_0>(long, unsigned int) + 530
...

While emitting IR SIL function @_TFE4mainPS_4Some5takeWfT1wwx1W_T_ for 'takeW' at main.swift:11:5
```

**Is mixing `@objc` and `associatedtype` is inherently wrong, or is it plain compiler bug?**

```
swiftc --version
Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Comment: This might be related to the fact that [methods in protocol extensions are dispatched statically](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/06/kevin-ballard-swift-dispatch/), but I can't leave any insights beyond this prompt. None the less, no matter the reason, the compiler shouldn't crash.

Comment: I tested this and I get the same crash. You might want to file a Swift bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associated types are Swift-only feature, not visible to Objective-C, so there should be compiler error.

Filed a bug https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3850